# How can I dump SQLite database tables (that uses BLOB type) using Qt?

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite, qbytearray

How can I dump **SQLite** database tables (that uses **BLOB** type) using **Qt**?

I have a `QVector<double>` that I convert to `QByteArray` and save it into the database as **BLOB**.

I'm using the following function to serialize the `QVector<double>` to a `QByteArray`:

```
QByteArray Serialize::serialize(QVector<double> data)
{
    QByteArray byteArray;
    QDataStream out(&byteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << data;
    return byteArray;
}
```

When I load the **BLOB** field from the database I use the deserialize function to get the `QVector<double>` again.

```
void Serialize::deserialize(QByteArray byteArray, QVector<double> *data)
{
    QDataStream in(&byteArray, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    in >> *data;
}
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658120/how-to-dump-all-tables-of-a-sqlite-db-with-qt), the `.dump` command is implemented in the **sqlite** command line application, not in the **SQLite** library itself. Then, as I understood I need to manually create my **SQL** file.

I already created a function to select all data from all tables and create **SQL** insert statements to insert into the **SQL** file.

The problem is that I don't know how to insert the `QByteArray` (**BLOB**) data into the **SQL** statements that it can be imported into another database in the future.

I'm using Qt 5.3.

**Note**: this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618222/how-can-i-convert-qbytearray-to-string-in-qt-5-3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not solved the specific problem, but I gave up on creating the **SQL** file.
I used the `byteArray.toHex()` command to generate the **SQL** file just for test purposes but it generated an **SQL** file much bigger than my database file (.db).

For example, my database file has 174 mb and the **SQL** file generated has 331 mb.

Then I gave up on creating the **SQL** file and I'm exporting a copy of my database file (.db) and then importing it to the system when needed.

To do so, I just create a new connection and copy all the content from this database file exported to my current database file.

As I said, this is not an answer to my question but it is a workaround for my general issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code;

```
  QSqlQuery insertQuery(myDatabase);

  insertQuery.prepare("insert into images (name, data) values (:name, :data);");

  insertQuery.bindValue(":name",myImageName);
  insertQuery.bindValue(":data",*picture);

  insertQuery.exec();
```

where picture is of type QByteArray*.